# any changes added to my CSS are no longer being applied in my PHP

Tags: php, html, css

everything was working fine then randomly any CSS I add to my Message-inbox.CSS or any other CSS file in my project none of the added CSS gets applied I'm using a required once to link the header and footer and a html link for the pages own CSS. below is the links and my CSS code. I have tried clearing my browser cache and other data and also tried the link with the echo to stop storing cache but no results.

```
<?php
  require_once "../addons/header.php";
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Messages-inbox.css" type="text/css"/>


.secondarynavigation-messages a:hover {
  color: #fd886b;
  border: 1px solid #fd886b;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.secondarynavigation-messages a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.secondarynav-messages ::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.secondarynavigation-messages a::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fd886b;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.messages-nav-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e1;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: You should wrap your css code with `<style>` tag. Like this `<style>
.secondarynavigation-messages a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to options.

1. Check whether your CSS can be accesed from the URL that you provide. Just open up source code in Chrome (Ctrl+U) and try clicking on your linked CSS file and check whether browser opens it, and it is the correct file.
2. In order to avoid cache just add version to your css file in the section in HTML where you refer to it, not the of the file itself in the storage, smth like "style.css?v=1". Any new parameter will be considered as new file by browsers and they will redownload that. And it won't affect your code.

To clarify, do smth like this:

```
<link href="/css/stylesnew.css?v=1.1" rel="stylesheet">
```